# Increase Heap Space Available for JVM: OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceed VM limit Ubuntu 64Bit Neo4j 2.0

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm, neo4j, py2neo

**My specs:**

-Ubuntu 64bit

-Neo4j 2.0

-32 GB of Ram

-AMD FX-8350 Eight COre Processor

**The problem:**

I'm making a request to my Neo4j server with the following query:

```
MATCH (being:my_label_2) RETURN being
```

And gives me this error:

```
OutOfMemoryError

Requested array size exceeds VM limit

StackTrace:
java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300)
java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:916)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.toBytes(OutputFormat.java:194)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:147)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:130)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:67)
org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:101)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)
org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
```

This works fine with "my_label_1" which returns around 30k results

**What I believe is the problem:**

I don't have enough memory allocated to my JVM

**Attempts made to fix/things I've found online:**

[I read what the manual says to do](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-jvm.html)

[And what the Ubuntu Forums say to do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107665/how-do-i-change-java-runtime-parameters)

So I've tried going to my neo4 folder (with cd as usual) and running it with the arguments this way:

```
sudo bin/neo4j start -Xmx4096M
```

However that didn't work. When Neo4j starts it does warn me that I might not have enough space with:

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

**Question**

I know I'm definitely using the arguments wrong, I honestly don't have much experience with JVM configurations. How should I approach this, am I missing something?

Comment: use the header X-Stream:true then the results will be streamed to the client. how do you make your request in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put JVM setting into the `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf` file. It should look like this:

```
user@pc:> head -n 7 neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf
wrapper.java.additional=-Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties
wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties
wrapper.java.additional=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Note that you can configure different aspects of neo4j via different files, so it's better to read description to every file in that `conf/` directory in order to get familiar with what can be done and how exactly.

Comment: I had figured it out, but this is exactly what I had to do to fix it. Great answer!